# Can i create a filename with 2 dots?

Tags: filenames

I need to set a wallpaper in a GPO and the file name must be wallpaper1. and the file extension is jpg.So is there any way to keep that dot in a filename?As I know wallpaper1..jpg is not a valid filename. Any suggestions how to keep that dot in a filename?

Comment: Two or more consecutive dots are perfectly valid filenames. The real question is, why does that matters?

Comment: Which system? Windows, Linux..?

Comment: Its part of an exam...so just to recap wallpaper..jpg is a valid windows filename?